# is it possible to display literals in graphdb workbench visual graph?

Tags: graphdb

I'm using GraphDB 9.4 free edition with the Workbench web interface on Ubuntu 18.04.

I have a construct sparql query that shows all the correct triples, including literals, in the output below the query box. When I click on the "Visual" button to display the graph, the literals and associated data properties are not shown. Is there a setting to display them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, that functionality doesn't exist.

If you click on the node though, the data properties show up on the right side of the screen. But I totally agree, a function to display them directly would be nice.